# Manhwa/Manhua/Webtoon The Mc has white hair and he train with the demon king and the demon kill him and res him again countless times

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember there was a guy with anubis mask with the mc and there was some guys that was called administrators or something like that and the mc fought with some kind of mushroom monster in a test to get his class or something like that .

that's all the things i remember

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When were you reading this?  What site were you reading it on or where did you find the link to it?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was in Full colour

Comment: DavidW all that i remember is that i found it from a video with music the mc was wearing black clothes and was fighting a mushroom monster that had a shape like a human but covered in mushroom

Comment: Do you still have a link to this video? This would be easier to find with the original images that you saw.